# MVC Tell one view to one use controller, and another view to use another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an application where I don't want to use any "folders". EG

http://mydomain/Index , 
http://mydomain/Edit , 
http://mydomain/Admin , 
and so on....

I modified my defauly RouteConfig initially to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "maproute1",
   url: "{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have a Views/Home folder with all my views.

It works like a charm so whenever I enter the actionname, I don't have any issues.

If, hypothetically, I wanted to KEEP this url structure the same where I ONLY show the root domain / action-page... and I want to have SOME of these actions use one controller (HomeController.cs) and other actions (e.g. Admin) use another contoller (AdminController), is there I way I can modify my routes to say... ok.. if the action is "Admin" then use the AdminController? I have the AdminController set up with the action for "Admin" defined. I tried changing my routeconfig like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "maproute1",
   url: "{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "maproute2",
   url: "{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then I set up a Views/Admin folder for the Admin view (and some other actions/views I want)

But it doesn't work. *IF* I have an "Admin" action in the home controller, it fires from the home controller. But I want the action to fire from the AdminController. Keep in mind I'm not just going to use ActionLinks to navigate to these pages so I can't just use an Actionlink and specify the controller. Some people are going to be going to links via a direct URL/bookmark.

If I wanted to keep my URL structure like this (http://mydomain/Action) I *could* just slap all my actions into ONE single controller and it would work, but I like to keep my code neat so that one controller handles functionality related to one set of models and another controller related to another set of models. For now it seems like I have to either (a) have one MASSIVE controller that is just going to get bigger and bigger or (b) I HAVE to have a more detailed path in there to have something to tell MVC what controller to use.

(BTW, I can't use querystrings... long story... don't ask)

MVC was designed to give people more control over layout from what I understand. I've been a web forms programmer for 13 years, but so far it seems that MVC has done this at the expense of giving you less control in other areas.

Comment: No you cannot (unless you created a specific route definition for every action). If you do not identify the controller (or an alias for it) in the url then how would the server know which controller to call - its not psychic!

Comment: Creating a specific route for every action is a solution that I would try (such as in one of the answers below).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to hardcode your Action names in your routes.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "maproute1",
           url: "Home/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "maproute2",
           url: "Admin/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

http://localhost/Admin should take you to the Admin/Index view and http://localhost/Home should go to Home/Index view

Comment: Sure enough, this worked. I wonder how  (or if) it would work if I had the same action name for different controllers. I doubt it would work, but luckily that's not my case. All my action names are unique across all controllers. The only thing to keep in mind with this approach is that in the defaults, the "action = 'actionname'" MUST be specified and must match the action name set in the URL otherwise you get a "research not found" error.

Comment: I know this method may seem weird, but I'm not a fan of how MS tries to shove their URL naming conventions on you. After working with webforms for 14+ years and recently forcing myself to move to MVC the last 2 years, this is my only real gripe about it. Not every website is an online store where you really want to comply with SEO URL conventions. Some people want to have more control over their URL.

Comment: if you dig into routing, you'll probably be surprised how flexible it really is. one thing to remember is always have a default route that leads somewhere and put it last in the list. `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Answer (score 0):

one simple workaround is to create an admn action in home controller and then redirect from there to Admin controller but i am not sure you want to do ths as it may hit performence

```
public ActionResult Admin()
{ 
 return Redirect("Admin/Index");
}
```

i would say try something other if you can and even then if you cant find a way out use this workaround

Comment: That was actually the first thing that popped into my head. The hardcoded action names in the routeconfig.cs file seems to have done the trick and seems like a cleaner approach as least from an organizational perspective.. I may have to do an experiment to see which method is actually more efficient from an execution-time standpoint.